# CSS resize image by half or any percent

Tags: css

I'm trying to shrink an image in React within my CSS file to be smaller than the original by 50%, here is my current attempt:

```css
.logo {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

With this however, the image is not perfectly reduced. I want to be able to reduce an image by any% of its current size - how can I achieve this?

Comment: Define "_perfect_" please. Describe "_didn't work as I expected_" please. At this point it seems highly unlikely anyone will be able to meet your expectations - even if we knew what they were. It sound as if you need to create a "_perfect_" version of the image at the smaller size.

Comment: You haven't told us what is wrong compared to what you expect. Please provide a [mre]. Note that changing percentage of both height and width assumes that the aspect ratio of the parent is same as the image. If not you will see distortion

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to achieve this is by giving making the parent element an `inline-block`, this then allows you to be able to manipulate the `width` of the image and reduce it to 50%, or any other size as required.

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}

.w-50 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span>
    <h3>Original Size</h3>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png"/>
</span>

<span class="inline">
    <h3>50% Reduced</h3>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png" class="w-50" />
</span>
```